# Ant Design React. Bootstrap Grid "container" concept

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, antd, antd-mobile

Is there in Ant Design for React the Bootstrap Grid **"container"** concept?

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap
>   and are required when using our default grid system. Choose from a
>   responsive, fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at
>   each breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time).
>
> While containers can be nested, most layouts do not require a nested
>   container.
>
> ```
> <div class="container">
>   <!-- Content here -->
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 12):

Antd doesn't provide a container within it's grid system. 
But you can create your own container class.

Here's how you can do it:

```
@import "~antd/lib/style/index";

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.make-container(@minWidth, @breakpoint) {
    @media (min-width: @minWidth) {
        .container {
            max-width: @breakpoint;
        }
    }
}

.make-container(@screen-xs-min, @screen-xs);
.make-container(@screen-sm-min, @screen-sm);
.make-container(@screen-md-min, @screen-md);
.make-container(@screen-lg-min, @screen-lg);
.make-container(@screen-xl-min, @screen-xl);
.make-container(@screen-xxl-min, @screen-xxl); // Optional
```

then you can use the class as you would in bootstrap

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work - is this SCSS?

Comment: I dont know how to use this. I only know how to write CSS inside App.css and makeStyles or custom styles inside JS files (material UI). 

Can you please elaborate how to use this code?

Comment: @beeftosino It's `less` variables ([antd-theme](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less)) , you will may need sth like `less-loader`

Answer (score 7):

Add this to some your CSS file

```
.container{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-left:15px
}
@media (min-width: 476px){
  .container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container{
    padding-right:15px;
    padding-left:15px
  }
}
@media (min-width: 476px){
  .container{
    width:100%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container{
    width:720px;
    max-width:100%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container{
    width:960px;
    max-width:100%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container{
    width:1140px;
    max-width:100%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px){
  .container{
    width:1340px;
    max-width:100%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, by looking through [the documentation](https://ant.design/components/grid/#Design-concept), they're grid system consists of `Col`s and `Row`s. Nothing like React-Bootstrap `<Grid />` (which is component for `container` class)

Answer (score 3):

Ant Design does not provide such functionality, you'll need to create it by your own. In addition to the CSS class approach already suggested, you could also create a React component. If you are using Styled Components it'd look something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const Container = styled.div`
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 1rem;

  @media (min-width: 576px) {
    max-width: 576px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    max-width: 768px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    max-width: 992px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1200px) {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }
`

function Container(props) {
  return <S.Container {...props} />
}

export default Container
```

Then you can use it as a regular React component:

```
<Container>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...
</Container>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a container from Row and Col

For the space of the sides

```
<Col xs={1} sm={2}></Col>
```

For the content

```
<Col xs={22} sm={20}><Col>
```

the sum of the 3 must give 24

Example:

```
<Row>
  <Col xs={1} sm={2}></Col>
  <Col xs={22} sm={20}>
    { Content }
  </Col>
  <Col xs={1} sm={2}></Col>
</Row>
```

If you need more breakpoint for the responsive use the other points: xs, sm, md, lg, xl, xxl.

Comment: Good practice to add links to the specific place of the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Create container component, is reusable and responsive

```js
// src/Components/Container .jsx
import { Row, Col } from 'antd'

const Container = (props) => {

    const { children } = props

    return (<Row className='container'>
        <Col xs={1} sm={2}></Col>
        <Col xs={22} sm={20}>
          { children }
        </Col>
        <Col xs={1} sm={2}></Col>
      </Row>)
}

export default Container
```

Usage

```js
// App.js
import Container from "@/Components/Container";

const App = () => {

    return(<Container>
            Content goes here
        </Container>)
}

export default App
```